# Installing ubuntu 15.10

Tags: system-installation

I am using a wipro laptop with an Intel 2nd generation B950 processor and 3GiB of RAM. I am dual booting with Windows 7 64-bit and a customized version of Ubuntu 11.

When I try to install Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit via bootable USB, it shows an error message and I am unable to install it. Is this an error in my BIOS setting or do I have to download a different version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error message?

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences using Ubuntu If one distribution does not work try another, 99% of the time one will work.

We don't know what the error message you are getting so we can only guess if may be a bad ISO file maybe not burned correctly.

If you have another **USB** drive you may also want to try that one also because they do get corrupted from time to time.

Also make sure you have the correct setting in your BIOS it differs with most machines.